# SQL update statement for various values

Tags: sql, db2

I am performing an update on a file that contains over 20 billion records through sql for as400.

```
   UPDATE "LIBRARY"/AR#RMTPRL9 
   SET SENTFLAG = ' ', DATESENT = '0001-01-01', TIMESENT = '00:00:00', XMITT# = 0, LOCATION = 'PACI175A', ARBATCH# = ' ‘ 
   WHERE LOCATION = 'PACI173A' AND ARBATCH# = 'PAR1981181'
```

How can I run this update for different values of arbatch# in a single query to save time?

eg: I would like to use the same update statement for ARBATCH# values PAR19811284, PAR18736765 etc.

REEDITS:

I have the following data:(Move these values to location EFG)

```
  LOCATION     ARBATCH#
  ABC          1234
  ABC          5468
  ABC          8765
  XYZ          6759
  XYZ          5432
```

Here i would like to achieve a query which would perform update for records as follows:

```
 UPDATE "LIBRARY"/AR#RMTPRL9 
   SET SENTFLAG = ' ', DATESENT = '0001-01-01', TIMESENT = '00:00:00', XMITT# = 0, LOCATION = 'EFG', ARBATCH# = ' ‘ 
   WHERE LOCATION = 'ABC' AND ARBATCH# = '1234'
```

Now how could i successfully use "in" for such an update

Comment: Sorry, it seems like my solution won't work for you, please edit your question explaining that clearly. Also take a look at the [`MERGE` statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010873.htm), it might be helpful.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Appreciate the help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'cheat' pretty trivially:

```
UPDATE "LIBRARY"/AR#RMTPRL9 
SET SENTFLAG = ' ', 
    DATESENT = '0001-01-01', TIMESENT = '00:00:00', 
    XMITT# = 0, 
    LOCATION = 'EFG', 
    ARBATCH# = ' ' 
WHERE (LOCATION, ARBATCH#) IN (VALUES ('ABC', '1234'),
                                      ('ABC', '5468'),
                                      ('ABC', '8765'),
                                      ('XYZ', '6759'),
                                      ('XYZ', '5432'))
```

(Statement run on my local iSeries DB2 instance)

Incidently, `DATESENT` and `TIMESENT` should be combined into a single timestamp, and probably be nullable, too.  I'd personally prefer something like `sentAt` for the name, not something including the type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `in`:

```
   UPDATE "LIBRARY"/AR#RMTPRL9 
   SET SENTFLAG = ' ', DATESENT = '0001-01-01', 
   TIMESENT = '00:00:00', XMITT# = 0, LOCATION = 'PACI175A', ARBATCH# = ' ' 
   WHERE LOCATION = 'PACI173A' AND ARBATCH# IN( 'PAR1981181', PAR18736765 etc ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. What if the value of LOCATION field changes in the SET clause and WHERE clause for different values of ARBATCH#?

Comment: then you can use `location in (..,.. etc)` is that what you are asking? :)